# Grub bootloader

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I have just switched to Linux and made a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 over Windows 10 (no dual boot). I want to skip the grub bootloader screen which appears at the startup. I have already gone through several posts which are written on this, but I still have the same issue. I have changed the grub config file and after changing it I saved the changes through a command as instructed.

Here is the config file.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"

export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/magenta"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="black/black"
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't actually mention what the problem is - so please clarify: What is the problem you experience? What happens now when you boot that is undesired?

Comment: Also, was the initial config file not working? By default, Grub is hidden and boots directly to Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually i wanna skip the grub bootloader screen where it ask for choosing the operating system i wanna boot into. As for the initial config file also, i had the same issue. There is a screen asking for choosing the os. I wanna skip that screen and want to boot directly into ubuntu

Comment: Can you please insert what the Grub menu looks like when you boot? Please insert a screenshot or photo, as this will help.

Comment: The grub menu will be displayed in some cases if there was a problem with one of the disks at shutdown, even if you set it to be hidden.

Comment: @ArturMeinild i have just uploaded a screenshot of boot screen

Comment: If you want to use a description as GRUB-DEFAULT= , it must match exactly to the default description. I might just change back to 0 to avoid description issues. Your last line does not have # to convert to comment? Do you then get an error message on `sudo grub-update` where is does not write grub.cfg but grub.cfg.new?

Comment: Also, as a workaround, you might change to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=3`. In this case, the menu will be there for only 3 seconds if you don't press anything, even if it still appears.

Comment: @oldfred no i haven't got any error while updating grub config file

Comment: @Artur still the same screen at the start with a timer of 30 seconds as shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing what others wrote here:

You are about to shoot yourself in the foot. You need that menu in case something goes wrong; sooner or later that *will happen*. Don't attempt to get rid of the Grub menu completely; give yourself a chance to fix things in the worst case. It's okay to minimize the timeout to 2 seconds, but don't try to remove the menu completely.

Considering how long everything else takes at boot time (memory and hardware self-test etc., loading the kernel, initializing the system with all the various system services), those 2 seconds won't kill you; but not having the ability to fix your system by booting a previous kernel will.

Take this advice from someone who has been working with Linux since the late 1990s.

---

Also, from your comments it sounds as if you might not be aware that you need to run `sudo update-grub` after you edited that config file: Only then will the changes be propagated from `/etc/default/grub` which you edited to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which is generated from your configuration in `/etc/default/grub` plus kernels and other operating systems that are found (at that time) on your disks.

If your changes never seem to take effect, check where Grub is actually installed to; if you use the legacy MBR partitioning scheme, make sure you install it to the MBR of the disk you are booting from. If there is a previous install of Grub and your current one was installed to another boot sector, it might still boot your system, but any changes you make to your current Grub will only affect a Grub that is never used.

If you do that, please check the documentation exactly how to do it; it might be a dangerous operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue is i cant even reduce it time to 3 second. It had no effect to the boot screen. (Same as shown in screenshot). And yes i am aware of sudo update-grub. I ran that command each time after changing the config file.

Comment: Then check if your changes actually arrived in `/boot/grub/menu.cfg`, and also if there is any similar entry _after_ yours.

Comment: Yes sir, just after my first installation I accidentally deleted the grub bootloader (as I was playing around my mistake) and after that, I took my life USB drive and installed ubuntu on the same disk again. If it's because of that then how can I fix it?

Comment: I "Erase everything" and used "LVM" as suggested by a friend during both installations. And there is no such file as  `/boot/grub/menu.cfg`

Comment: Sorry, that was `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.